# Change vectors to lists using postwalk

Tags: clojure

```
(postwalk #(do (println "visiting:" %)
               (if (vector? %)
                 (seq %)
                 %))
          [:title {:bu "hu"}])
```

What I expected(without printlns): `(:title {:bu "hu"})`

What I got:

```
visiting: :title
visiting: :bu
visiting: hu
visiting: [:bu hu]
Stack trace of root exception is empty; this is likely due to a JVM optimization 
that can be disabled with -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow.
java.lang.ClassCastException:
```

Why is it visiting `[:bu hu]` instead of `{:bu hu}`? It seems to work fine with nested vectors but toss a map in and the jvm gets angry at me and vomits unintelligible obscenity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get a better stack trace:

```
visiting: :title
visiting: :bu
visiting: hu
visiting: [:bu hu]

ClassCastException clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry  clojure.lang.ATransientMap.conj (ATransientMap.java:44)
```

`[:bu hu]` is not the map, it's the first `MapEntry` in the map. Unfortunately, it's not actually an instance of `clojure.lang.MapEntry`. `walk` turns it into a vector before the function you pass into the `postwalk` is ever applied (`postwalk` calls `walk` internally). Even after [reading the code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/2224dbad5534ff23d3653b07d9dc0a60ba076dd7/src/clj/clojure/walk.clj#L45) I still can hardly believe it.

I'm not sure what the best way around this is. But I thought it'd be helpful for you to at least know exactly why it's happening.

Comment: Nice insight (+1)! I love Clojure, but it's problems like this that make me remember why we invented static type systems for our programming languages....

Answer (score 1):

[:bu "hu"] is a clojure.lang.MapEntry, and postwalk will visit each entry in the map. Sadly, clojure.walk/postwalk passes MapEntry as a clojure.lang.PeristentVector, so you cannot reliably differentiate entries from vectors in postwalk. I think you will need to use your own walking implementation.